# Changing more than one style attribute with Javascript

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I need to change more than one style attribute for a given element. I know how to change one:     `document.getElementById(today).style.visibility= "visible";` 
but am unsure of the syntax for changing more than one e.g. visibility,width, height and font-color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just multiple calls:

```
document.getElementById(today).style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById(today).style.color = "red";
document.getElementById(today).style.height = "5em";
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. Next trick is one of the attributes that I am changing is font-size but it doesn't seem to like the "-" in
    document.getElementById(today).style.font-size= "x-small";

Comment: @Dave, for CSS properties that have contain dashes, you have to remove the dash, and uppercase the next character, i.e.: for `font-size`, you should use `fontSize`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to replace any other inline styles for that element you can use the style.cssText property.

```
document.getElementById('idstring').style.cssText=
'font-size:1em;color:blue;visibility:visible';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference each attribute one at a time, i.e. .style.width=, .style.height=, etc.

You could shorten the amount of typing you do a bit like so:

```
var g = document.getElementById(today);
g.style.width=100;
g.style.height=100;
g.style.visibility='visible';
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS way would be to create a class that does all the styling common to those elements and assign the class attribute to them,

alternatively, if they are inhertiable styles then put the elements in a common parent say div and set the div's style